# Is it possible in boost::ireplace to treat special characters like basic characters? (eg. 'ź' as 'z')

Tags: c++, boost, utf-8, str-replace

so, I am making a word filter which replaces bad words with asterixes, but there are so many possible combinations of words if special characters are used like ąężźć etc..

How can I make boost::ireplace_all treat those as basic characters aezzc?

so

`boost::ireplace_all("żąć", "a", "*");` and `boost::ireplace_all("zac", "a", "*");`

would result in `ż*ć` and `z*c` respectively?

Edit/Extended Example:

```
const std::set<std::string> badwords =
{
    "<not nice word>",
    "<another not nice word>"
};

void FilterBadWords(std::string& s)
{
    for (auto &badword : badwords)
        boost::ireplace_all(s, badword, "*");
}


int main()
{
    std::string a("hello you <not nice word> person");
    std::string b("hęlló you <nót Nićę wórd> person");
    FilterBadWords(a);
    FilterBadWords(b);
    //a equals "hello you * person"
    //b equals "hęlló you * person"
    //or as many * as the replaced string lenght, both are fine
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be boost ireplace or are you just looking for a solution to replacing ż by z, ć by c and so on?

Comment: I want to preserve the original tokens, but filter out "bad substrings" (replace with `*`), examle: `"hello you <not nice word> person"` and `"hęlló you <nót nićę wórd> person"` would both be respectively replaced as `"hello you *************** person"` and `"hęlló you *************** person"` (only and only if `<not nice word>` is in `std::set<std::string> BadWords`)

Comment: Other note, Unicode provides a [look-alikes list](http://www.unicode.org/Public/security/revision-06/confusables.txt) for this purpose.

Comment: @Mitch _confusables_ :) Anyhoops, found out that the OP likely doesn't want to use UNICODE at all. I'm guessing [ANSI CP852](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883220/is-it-possible-in-boostireplace-to-treat-special-characters-like-basic-charact#comment44175934_27883907)

Comment: @sehe, yep... don't know where I got "look-alikes" from when linking to a file called `confusables.txt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost Locale has support for primary collation, via ICU:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/locale/doc/html/collation.html

It proved very tricky to get it to work. Basically, with `char` strings you're toast, since Boost String Algorithms know nothing about code points and just iterate (*and compare*) the input sequences byte-for-byte (well, `char` by `char`, but that's a bit confusing here).

So, the solution lay in converting to utf32 strings (which is possible with GCC using `std::wstring` because `wchar_t` is 32 bit there). Utf16 should also generally "work" but it still has the traversal issues that I just outlined, only much more rarely.

Now, I've created a quick-and-dirty custom Finder predicate:

```
template <typename CharT>
struct is_primcoll_equal
{
    is_primcoll_equal(const std::locale& Loc=std::locale()) :
        m_Loc(Loc), comp(Loc, boost::locale::collator_base::primary) {}

    template< typename T1, typename T2 >
        bool operator()(const T1& Arg1, const T2& Arg2) const {
            // TODO use `do_compare` methods on the collation itself that
            // don't construct basic_string<> instances
            return 0 == comp(std::basic_string<CharT>(1, Arg1), std::basic_string<CharT>(1, Arg2));
        }

  private:
    std::locale m_Loc;
    boost::locale::comparator<CharT> comp;
};
```

It's **horribly inefficient** because it constructs single-character strings each call. This is because the `do_compare` method is not part of the public API for `collator<>`. I leave deriving a custom `collator<>` and using it as an exercise for the reader.

Next up, we mimick the `replace_all` interface by wrapping `find_format_all` instead:

```
 template<typename SequenceT, typename Range1T, typename Range2T>
    inline void collate_replace_all( 
            SequenceT& Input,
            const Range1T& Search,
            const Range2T& Format,
            const std::locale& Loc=std::locale() )
    {
        ::boost::algorithm::find_format_all( 
                Input, 
                ::boost::algorithm::first_finder(Search, is_primcoll_equal<typename SequenceT::value_type>(Loc)),
                ::boost::algorithm::const_formatter(Format) );
    }
```

Now we just need the string widening conversion(s) and we're good to go:

```
void FilterBadWords(std::string& s) {
    using namespace boost::locale::conv;

    std::wstring widened = utf_to_utf<wchar_t>(s, stop);

    for (auto& badword : badwords) {
        detail::collate_replace_all(widened, badword, L"*"/*, loc*/);
    }

    s = utf_to_utf<char>(widened, stop);
}
```

#### Full Program

**<kbd>[<strike>Live</strike> Broken¹ On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6e7c74cad612d76)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <set>
#include <string>

const std::set<std::string> badwords =
{
    "<not nice word>", 
    "<another not nice word>" 
};

namespace detail {
    template <typename CharT>
    struct is_primcoll_equal
    {
        is_primcoll_equal(const std::locale& Loc=std::locale()) :
            m_Loc(Loc), comp(Loc, boost::locale::collator_base::primary) {}

        template< typename T1, typename T2 >
            bool operator()(const T1& Arg1, const T2& Arg2) const {
                // assert(0 == comp(L"<not nice word>", L"<nót Nićę wórd>"));
                // TODO use `do_compare` methods on the collation itself that
                // don't construct basic_string<> instances
                return 0 == comp(std::basic_string<CharT>(1, Arg1), std::basic_string<CharT>(1, Arg2));
            }

      private:
        std::locale m_Loc;
        boost::locale::comparator<CharT> comp;
    };

    template<typename SequenceT, typename Range1T, typename Range2T>
        inline void collate_replace_all( 
                SequenceT& Input,
                const Range1T& Search,
                const Range2T& Format,
                const std::locale& Loc=std::locale() )
        {
            ::boost::algorithm::find_format_all( 
                    Input, 
                    ::boost::algorithm::first_finder(Search, is_primcoll_equal<typename SequenceT::value_type>(Loc)),
                    ::boost::algorithm::const_formatter(Format) );
        }
}

void FilterBadWords(std::string& s) {
    using namespace boost::locale::conv;

    std::wstring widened = utf_to_utf<wchar_t>(s, stop);

    for (auto& badword : badwords) {
        detail::collate_replace_all(widened, badword, L"*"/*, loc*/);
    }

    s = utf_to_utf<char>(widened, stop);
}

static_assert(sizeof(wchar_t) == sizeof(uint32_t), "Required for robustness (surrogate pairs, anyone?)");

int main()
{
    auto loc = boost::locale::generator().generate("");
    std::locale::global(loc);

    std::string a("hello you <not nice word> person");
    std::string b("hęlló you <nót Nićę wórd> person");

    FilterBadWords(a);
    FilterBadWords(b);
    std::cout << a << "\n";
    std::cout << b << "\n";
}
```

### Output

On my system:

```
hello you * person
hęlló you * person
```

---

**¹** Apparently locale support is incomplete in the Coliru execution environment

Answer (score 0):

As an additional solution that uses a bit less boost (well, you could edit it to remove boost completely..):

```
const std::vector<std::string> badwords = 
{ 
    "badword1",
    "badword2",
    "badword3",
    "badword4"
};

char PolishReplacement[0xFF];

const std::map<std::string, std::string> PolishReplacementMap =
{
    { "ł","l" },
    { "ą","a" },
    { "ę","e" },
    { "ć","c" },
    { "ż","z" },
    { "ź","z" },
    { "ó","o" },
    { "ś","s" },
    { "ń","n" },
    { "Ł","L" },
    { "Ą","A" },
    { "Ę","E" },
    { "Ć","C" },
    { "Ż","Z" },
    { "Ź","Z" },
    { "Ó","O" },
    { "Ś","S" },
    { "Ń","N" }
};

//preconstruct our array, we love speed gain by paying startup time
struct CPolishReplacementInitHack
{
    CPolishReplacementInitHack()
    {
        for (unsigned char c = 0; c < 0xFF; ++c)
        {
            char tmpstr[2] = { c, 0 };
            std::string tmpstdstr(tmpstr);
            auto replacement = PolishReplacementMap.find(tmpstdstr);
            if (replacement == PolishReplacementMap.end())
                PolishReplacement[c] = boost::to_lower_copy(tmpstdstr)[0];
            else
                PolishReplacement[c] = boost::to_lower_copy(replacement->second)[0];
        }
    }
} _CPolishReplacementInitHack;

//actual filtering
void FilterBadWords(std::string& s)
{
    std::string sc(s);
    for (auto& character : sc)
        character = PolishReplacement[(unsigned char)character];

    for (auto &badword : badwords)
    {
        size_t pos = sc.find(badword);
        size_t size = badword.size();
        size_t possize;

        while (pos != std::string::npos)
        {
            possize = pos + size;

            s.replace ( s.begin() + pos,  s.begin() + possize, "*");
            sc.replace(sc.begin() + pos, sc.begin() + possize, "*");

            pos = sc.find(badword);
        }
    }
}
```

This is probably non portable (Windows + Locale + encoding dependend?), but is is *very* fast (200 ms / 25000 random sentences, i7, debug, no optimizations).

Comment: Hmm. I can only assume it might work for you because you use ANSI strings with some code page other than 1252 and hence all these characters appear to be single-char? **And** you also happen to save the source file in exactly the same encoding and code page?! _Note [the assert line is never reached](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/825bc17204cbbcb1)_). You should have mentioned that you're not interested in UNICODE support if that is actually ok.

Comment: Of course, if this is what you actually wanted, be **sure** to use deterministic literals and document the chosen codepage assumptions, e.g. assuming code page 852: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fb0b0a17318c7a1)**